# add ljnigraphics to cmakeList

Tags: android, android-studio, cmake

[image: picture1]

I met the problem above,and I know I should add the library "ljnigraphics" to android.mk,but in android studio 2.2 there is no android.mk, so I add the library  to the CMakeList like this:

[image: picture2]

but it can not solve the problem. What should I do?

Comment: Instead of linking images, add error message and code into the question itself **as text**.

Comment: I just want know how to add the library "ljnigraphics"in CmakeList

Answer (score 2):

Just add this in the CMakeList.

```
target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                   native-lib
                   -ljnigraphics

                   # Links the target library to the log library
                   # included in the NDK.
                   ${log-lib} )
```